# Need the latest method to create and connect to a remote Selenium Chrome webdriver session on a local Windows PC

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In 2021, in Python, I was able to create a remote Selenium Chrome webdriver session (only a regular webdriver session, nothing special) on a Windows PC:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check")
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service", False}
prefs = {"profile.password_manager_enabled" : False}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
   "download.default_directory": r"C:\SeleniumDownload",
   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
   "download.directory_upgrade": True,
   "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
   "credentials_enable_service": False,
   "profile.password_manager_enabled" : False
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chromeOptions)
browserSessionInfo = [["_url", driver.command_executor._url], ["session_id", driver.session_id]]
```

Example value of `browserSessionInfo`:

```
print(browserSessionInfo)
[['_url', 'http://localhost:60318'], ['session_id', '7318ae0091d9ebada9a382c35f8ffd4a']]
```

This is how I connected to the above session in a separate script on the same PC in 2021:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = browserSessionInfo["_url"], desired_capabilities = {})
driver.close() # this prevents the dummy browser
driver.session_id = browserSessionInfo["session_id"]
(I continue to interact with the Remote driver normally here)
```

Documentation was almost nonexistent as I found only 1 post that talked about the above method and it worked.

Then I stopped using the above script. It is now 2024 and the above method doesn't work anymore. The arg `desired_capabilities` is no longer valid in `webdriver.Remote` . It seems to have been converted to `options`.

I try passing various options to `options` but nothing has worked so far.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = browserSessionInfo["_url"], options = webdriver.ChromeOptions())

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=60318): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001A335135010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

All the remote webdriver articles on Google either talk about Selenium Grid which was not required for the above method to work in 2021, or those articles are already outdated because they mention the arg `desired_capabilities`.

Would anybody be able to get it to work nowadays?

Comment: You can probably just use the debugging port.  So just something like chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=60318").  It should use the same session.  (If you set to same sessionID I think it'll cause an orphaned browser process)  Just use same constructor... no "Remote".